# HDFStore error appending - "Cannot serialize the column"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df:

```
    datetime                      bid      ask     bidvolume  askvolume
0   2007-03-30 21:00:00.332000   1.9682   1.9678       4         0.8
```

Trying to append this to a new datastore. The datastore does not exist so I use the following to create and append the data;

```
store = pd.HDFStore(storePath,mode='w')
store.append('data',df)
store.close()
```

I get this error: on the `store.append` line.

```
TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [bid] because
its data contents are [floating] object dtype
```

How do I get the data to store properly?

Comment: do ``df.dtypes``. you have ``object`` dtypes on the columns (the message indicates that they look like ``float`` type, but they are not typed that way. You need to convert as @Phillip Cloud suggest below (or event better convert when you are reading them in). It is hard to create object dtyped floating values unless you are doing it on purpose (that's why I say when you read it in)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Please note: the following method `convert_objects()` is now deprecated and may not work*
Call `DataFrame.convert_objects()`:

```
df = DataFrame(randn(10, 1), dtype=object).convert_objects()
df.to_hdf('/tmp/blah.h5', 'df', append=True)
```

It might be worth checking to see if you can get your data in the correct format before you start saving to HDF5. For example, wherever `df` is created, convert the objects there, instead of converting them when you save. In general, operations in pandas will be very cumbersome with a `Series` of `float`s with a `dtype` of `object`. Your life will be much easier if you convert your object arrays (where possible) as soon as you need to do anything with them.

Comment: Thanks. What's the advantage to using `dtype=object` here rather than, say, `dtype=numpy.float64` ?

Comment: Nothing. You shouldn't use `object`. I was using it to reproduce the issue. If you have floating point values, avoid the `object` dtype.

Comment: When facing "TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [myvar] because its data contents are [mixed] object dtype", I tried .convert_objects(), and that too failed, with " *** AssertionError: Block ref_items must be BlockManager items"

Comment: That might be a bug. Can you post a reproducible example over at the pandas github and I'll take a look?

Comment: This answer needs to be updated as .convert_objects is now deprecated.

Comment: @RexFuzzle what is the alternative?

Comment: Example of how to convert all the rows of the column`item_id` to strings (provided that this is possible): `df["item_id"] = df["item_id"].map(str)`